# Why does the first column expand in this table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why is this sample table, the first column is expanded so much while the others shrink?

```
<html>  
<head>  
   <style type="text/css">
      table,th, td,{
    width:100%;   
    border: 4px, solid;   
    border-collapse:collapse;   
       }    
   </style>  
</head>  
<body>  

<table>  
<tr>  
    <th>First Name</th>   
    <th>Last Name</th>   
    <th>Date</th>   
    <th>Notes</th>   
</tr>   
<tr>   
    <td>Jill</td>   
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Jill</td>  
    <td>Smith</td>   
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Eve </td>  
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>   
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>John </td>  
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Adam </td>  
    <td>Johnson</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  


</table>  



</body>  
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I've just put your code into a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uFDD/ And it all seems fine. Maybe there is something else on the page causing the table to stretch?

Comment: Let us know what browsers have this problem. There is no other html, styles or js I assume?

Comment: @Jamil:IE 9 in Vista. All code is posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `width: 100%;` for `td` -> `table,th, td`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7uFDD/3/)

It should be

```
table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;   
}

table, th, td {   
    border: 4px solid #aaa;   /* You were wrong here too */

}
```

Side Note: You have a stray `,` in this selector `table,th, td,`. Also this will select all `table` `th` and `td` elements in your document, so consider providing a class and using a selector like

```
.class_name table, .class_name table th, .class_name table td {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to set the column's width to 25% if you want every column having the same width.

**Solution**:

http://jsfiddle.net/XAZKT/

```
table {
    width:100%;   
    border: 4px, solid;   
    border-collapse:collapse;   
}

th { width: 25% }
```

Comment: The width:25% of td is 25% of the width of the table?

Comment: yes, the table width is 100%. you've 4 colums, so you've to give every column a quarter of the total size, in percent: 25%.

Answer (score 0):

put th and td width separately

```
table {
  width:100%;   
  border: 4px, solid;   
  border-collapse:collapse;   
}

th { width: 25% } 
td { width:25%}
```

Comment: The `width:25%` of `td` is `25%` of the width of the table?